# How would I make a list of enums?

Tags: java, enums

I would like to create a list that holds in it several enums. 
For example a list containing Days and Weather.

```
public enum Days {
SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WENESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY;
}

public enum Weather {
CLOUDY, CLEARSKIES, SUNNY, RAIN, SNOW;
}
```

Comment: More just a list allowing both Days and Weather to be passed and then accessed via specifying an index.  Some ideas I heard was to make it a list enum ? or object

Comment: I don't see any sensible meaning for a list (=ordered collection) where the elements are either days or weather.  Would a list of { day, weather } pairs make more sense?   Or even a map from day to weather?  Please say more about why you want this as a list.

Comment: You can put them in a `List<Enum<?>>`, or `List<Object>` for that matter. But this sounds like a probable [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider an interface and make them both implement that interface. Then you get to store a list of objects that implement that interface.

```
interface Parent {

}

public enum Days implements Parent {
    SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WENESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY;
}

public enum Weather implements Parent {
    CLOUDY, CLEARSKIES, SUNNY, RAIN, SNOW;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Parent[] list = new Parent[2];
list[0] = Days.FRIDAY;
list[1] = Weather.SNOW;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them:

```
class EnumWrapper {
    final Enum<?> val;
    final boolean isWeather;

    EnumWrapper(Days d) {
        val = d;
    }

    EnumWrapper(Weather w) {
        val = w;
        isWeather = true;
    }

    Days getDay() {
        if(!isWeather) return (Days) val;
        return null;
    }

    Weather getWeather() {
        if(isWeather) return (Weather) val;
        return null;
    }
}
```